# Mousehover to return text in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, foreach

I am new to knockout, I have a table binded with foreach and it has a priority name column in it displaying short cut name for each priority

I have this in my HTML

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ABCD()" >
  <td data-bind="if: PriorityId > 0">
    <span id="saPrior" data-bind="text:$root.prty Shortcut, event: { mouseover: $root.enabledetails, mouseout: $root.disabledetails },"></span>
  </td>
</tbody>
```

and my JS contains

```
 var enabledetails = function (opt) {
            // alert(opt.PriorityName);
            var temp = opt.PriorityName
            //alert(temp);
            return temp;
};
```

My observable ABCD contains the full name of the priority in a different variable which I am passing into enable details as opt object.
When I have an alert its displaying the correct name but when I return that name in this function nothing happens.

Am I missing some declarations somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a return in an event handler function, you just ask knockout to allow or not the default action to be called.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html